# make a function recursive

Tags: python, for-loop, recursion

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

queue = list()
crawled = set()
baseUrl = 'https://www.example.com'
url = 'https://www.example.com/'
    
def get_http_response(url):
    header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.11',
       'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
       'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
       'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
       'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
       'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
    set(queue)
    if url not in queue:
        queue.add(url)
    list(queue) 
             
    request = urllib.request.Request(url, headers = header) #urllib.request.Request object
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)  #http.client.HTTPResponse
    crawled.add(url)
    return response

def get_html_content(httpResponse):
    httpResponse_content = httpResponse.read() #data in bytes
    httpResponse_htmlContent = BeautifulSoup(httpResponse_content, 'html.parser')
    return httpResponse_htmlContent
    
def make_proper_links(hrefs,baseUrl):
    for i in range(len(hrefs)):
        if hrefs[i].startswith('/'):
            hrefs[i] = baseUrl + hrefs[i]
        else:
            hrefs[i] = hrefs[i]
    return hrefs
    

def link_finder(html, baseUrl):
    all_tags_with_hrefs = html.select('[href]') 
    all_hrefs = list()
    for i in range(len(all_tags_with_hrefs)):
        all_hrefs.append(all_tags_with_hrefs[i]['href'])
    all_hrefs = list(set(all_hrefs))  
    all_links = make_proper_links(all_hrefs, baseUrl)
    for i in range(len(all_links)):
        if all_links[i] not in queue:
             queue.append(all_links[i])
        else:
            continue
    return all_links

    
def main(url,baseUrl):
    if len(queue)==0:
        queue.append(url)
    else:
        pass  
    length = len(queue)
    for i in range(length):
        if queue[i] not in crawled:
            get_response = get_http_response(queue[i])
            html_content = get_html_content(get_response)
            links = link_finder(html_content, baseUrl)
        else:
            continue

main(url, baseUrl)
```

I want to call the main() to call the other functions and perform their task.
In the main function, I want the part :

```
for i in range(length):
        if queue[i] not in crawled:
            get_response = get_http_response(queue[i])
            html_content = get_html_content(get_response)
            links = link_finder(html_content, baseUrl)
        else:
            continue
```

to keep on going until the last element of queue list.
but the problem is that for every i, the length of the queue list may/may not increase.
how do I update the length for every iteration and then call the for loop till that new updated length?
I'm unable to develop the logic for it.
Any help will be much appreciated!!

Comment: You better use `while` for this, i.e. `while not len(queue) == 0: my_element = queue.pop()`. `pop` removes a single element from the list. this way, you don't have to worry about indices.

Comment: You can use `while not len(queue) == 0:` or `while len(queue) > 0:` or `while queue:` instead of `for i in range(length):`.